# How can Scala.js test whether a class variable was set to undefined by js.native processes?

Tags: scala.js

Please consider this Scala.js class:

```
@JSExport class Example(@JSExport var x: Uint8ClampedArray) { ... }
```

***edit:*** [this used to read: `case class Example(var x: Array[Int]) { ... }`]

Now suppose that a JavaScript native process occasionally sets the value of the Example.x class variable to `undefined`.  How, from a method inside of the Example class, would you test to see if the value of x is `undefined` or a legitimate array of Int values?

Would you just use: `js.typeOf(x) == "undefined"`?  Would that work?  Are there alternatives?  If so, what advantages and disadvantages do they have?

Comment: "Now suppose that a JavaScript native process occasionally sets the value of the Example.x class variable to undefined." That's not possible. The type of this thing is `Array[Int]`, which is either `null` or an actual `Array[Int]`. It *cannot* be `undefined`.

Comment: @sjrd I've edited the example to bring it closer to the real situation.  I have encountered two ways that x can be undefined.

1.  I have variable e, a global instance of Example available in the browser's JavaScript console.  Then I type: `e.x$1 = undefined`.
2.  e.x gets transferred to a web worker and then e.x is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you have a `Uint8ClampedArray`, which is a JavaScript type, Scala.js does not give any guarantee that, at run-time, it indeed holds a value which is a `Uint8ClampedArray`. In that case, you can indeed either use

```
js.typeOf(x) == "undefined"
```

or even

```
(x: Any) == js.undefined
```

The "recommended" way is to use

```
js.isUndefined(x)
```

but the other ones are just as correct.

---

Btw: you say in your comment that the JavaScript code does `e.x$1 = undefined`. That's *undefined behavior*, and will break in fullOpt. You need to use `e.x = undefined`, which is available thanks to the `@JSExport` on `var x`.

Comment: Thank you, Sébastien.  For the insights, and for creating Scala.js  :)